# How to change sql query to LINQ

Tags: sql, linq

How to change the following sql query to LINQ

```
select top(5) * 
from Tradingdays 
where Trading_date <'2014-10-16 00:00:00.000' 
  and holiday !=1 
order by id desc
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime yourDate = new  DateTime(2014,10,16,0,0,0,0);   
var list = (from t in datacontext.TradingDays
            where t.Trading_date < yourDate && t.holiday != 1
            orderby t.id desc
            select t).Take(5);
```